# C#, PostgreSQL | Получение нескольких записей из таблицы по внешнему ключу

Tags: c#, postgresql, select

есть 2 таблицы "Я" и "Друзья", как загнать всех друзей по отдельности в разные модели и вернуть все 3 модели? Через цикл? Если можно пример, заранее благодарю!

```
    public static Model_Друзья(int Я_id)
    {
        Model Друг  = new Model();
        using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT name, age FROM Схема.Друзья WHERE Внешний ключ_Я_id = @Я_id;");
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Я_id);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            using (NpgsqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    Друг.Id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                    Друг.Name = reader.GetString(1);
                    Друг.Age = reader.GetInt32(2);
                    conn.Close();
                    return Друг;
                }
                conn.Close();
                return Друг;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: offtop: русское именование - зло

Comment: Что такое `Друг`? Где вы создаёте эту переменную?

Comment: Уберите `LIMIT 1` и вам вернется список всех друзей в виде массива.

Comment: @SultanovShamil Это для наглядности

Comment: @АндрейNOP Это модель. Подправил*

Comment: @becouse А как их разместить по разным моделям?
сделать 3 Model Друг1  = new Model(); Model Друг2  = new Model();
 Model Друг3  = new Model(); и потом 
Друг1.Id = reader.GetInt32(0);
Друг1.Name = reader.GetString(1); 

Друг2.Id = reader.GetInt32(3);
Друг2.Name = reader.GetString(4); и потом return Друг1, Друг2, Друг3 ,так?

Comment: И еще, а если их(Друзей) там не 3 а 2 или 1, то в  Друг3.Name = reader.GetString(12) ничего не будет?

Comment: А что вы хотите получить? Какую задачу решаете?

Comment: @becouse Есть аккаунт, у аккаунта есть друзья, получить одним запросом все данные о друзьях и вставить данные в модель(Друг).

Comment: Уберите LIMIT 1 и вам вернется список всех друзей в виде массива. Этот массив и есть модель.

Comment: @becouse Это я понял, т.е в этом массиве данные будут лежать последовательно(ID первого Друга, name первого Друга..., ID второго Друга, name второго Друга и так далее), да?

Comment: Да. Но имейте в виду, что данные в БД лежат в произвольном порядке, так что есть смысл добавить сортировку по имени, например.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал вот так, мб кому поможет. Всем спасибо.

```
   public static List<FriendsModel> GetPlayerIDEasy(int accountID)
    {
        List<FriendsModel> friends= new List<FriendsModel>();
        using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT id, name, cash, age FROM server.friends WHERE id_account = @id;");
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", accountID);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            using (NpgsqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    FriendsModel friend = new FriendsModel();
                    friend .Id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                    friend .Name = reader.GetString(1);
                    friend .Age = reader.GetInt32(2);
                    friends.Add(friend );
                }
                conn.Close();
                return friends;
            }               
        }
    }
```